# CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, maximum trigger depth exceeded

Tags: apex, trigger, recursion

Here is my apex class :

```
public class AdobeToLead {

    public static void leadFunctionalities(List<Lead> leads)  {

        Set<String> accNames = new Set<String>();
        List<Lead> leadadd = new List<Lead>();
        List<Webinar_Attendee__c> wadd = new List<Webinar_Attendee__c>();

        List<Account> acclist =[SELECT id,Name from Account];
        for(Account a : acclist){
            accNames.add(a.Name);   
        }
        for(Lead l : leads){

            if(accNames.contains(l.Company)){

                List<Contact> clist = [Select ID From Contact Where Account.Name=:l.Company AND LastName=:l.LastName LIMIT 1];
                System.debug('clist ::: '+clist);
                if(clist!=null){
                    for(Contact c1 : clist){

                        Webinar_Attendee__c  wa = new Webinar_Attendee__c();
                        wa.Contact__c = c1.id;

                        l.addError('Duplicate Found');
                    }

                }
            }
            else{

                Lead ll = new Lead();
                ll.LastName = l.LastName;
                System.debug('LastName::: '+l.LastName);
                ll.Company = l.Company;
                System.debug('Company::: '+l.Company);
                ll.Status = l.Status;
                System.debug('Status ::: '+l.Status);
                leadadd.add(ll);
                System.debug('lead add:::'+leadadd);

                LightiningEd__Webinar__c lw = [select id,OwnerId,Name from LightiningEd__Webinar__c limit 1];
                System.debug('lw :::'+lw);

                Webinar_Attendee__c wae = new Webinar_Attendee__c();
                wae.Name = l.FirstName;
                System.debug('Webinar attendee Name :::'+wae.Name);
                wae.LightiningEd__Last_Name__c = l.LastName;
                System.debug('Webinar attendee Last Name :::'+wae.LightiningEd__Last_Name__c);
                wae.LightiningEd__Account_Name__c = l.LightiningEd__Account_Name__c;
                System.debug('Webinar attendee Account_Name :::'+ wae.LightiningEd__Account_Name__c);
                wae.LightiningEd__Webinar__c = lw.OwnerId;
                System.debug('Webinar attendeeWebinar Id :::'+ lw.OwnerId);
                wadd.add(wae);
                System.debug('wadd add:::'+wadd);
            }

        }

        if(!leadadd.isEmpty()){

            insert(leadadd);
        }
        if(!wadd.isEmpty()){

            insert(wadd);
        }


    }
}
```

Trigger :

```
trigger AdobeToLead on Lead (before insert,before update) {
        AdobeToLead.leadFunctionalities(Trigger.new);

}
```

When I execute this class, I get this error:

> Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, LightiningEd.AdobeToLead: maximum trigger depth exceeded

Comment: remove this line: `insert(leadadd);`. It's recursively calling the same trigger. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: i checked like this insert leadadd; still getting the same exception but how can i insert records (else condition executes)

Answer (score 3):

You can not create a new SObject record within a before insert/update trigger of the same SObject type.  You are just creating a infinite, recursive loop.  Here is what is happening:

1. `insert` or `update` is called on a new `Lead`
2. `AdobeToLead` trigger is fired BEFORE that record is saved to the database
3. `AdobeToLead` calls `AdobeToLead.leadFunctionalities` (side note, I would strongly recommend not having a trigger and class with the same name) with the unsaved `Lead` object in the argument list
4. From within `AdobeToLead.leadFunctionalities`, a new `Lead` is instantiated and `insert` is called on it
5. BEFORE this new record is saved to the database, `AdobeToLead` is fired
6. Steps 2-5 are repeated

This is happening over and over again.  Looking at your code, there is no reason to create a new `Lead`; you already have a `Lead` object that is in the process of saving.  I recommend splitting your Trigger into 2 parts.  Keep the duplication check in the before insert and move the creation of the `Webinar_Attendee__c` record to a after insert.